# linq: how to get sorted records from last ID

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-objects

I have the following table,

```
ItemTable, 

Col1 : ItemID(int)
Col2 : MRP(Decimal)
```

To one of the application I needed to pass selected number of items at a time, They will send me the lastId which I passed to them, the initial requirement was to pass the newest items, which I was able to get it using following query,

```
var itemList = itemRepository.AsQueryable()
             .Where(r => r.ProductID == productID && r.IsActive == true && r.ItemID< lastId)                                            
             .OrderByDescending(r => r.ItemID)
             .Take(numberOfItems)
             .ToList();
```

However now there is a sort option added to it, which is the MRP column, though again i have only the last Id with me, how could I will able to get this? I tried with the following query, no luck.

```
var itemList = itemRepository.AsQueryable()
                 .Where(r => r.ProductID == productID && r.IsActive == true && r.ItemID< lastId)                                            
                 .OrderByDescending(r => r.ItemID)
                 .OrderBy(r => r.MRP)
                 .Take(numberOfItems)
                 .ToList();
```

**UPDATE : Working Code**

As per CamperWill's suggesstion I updated my code and works great with skip.

```
var itemList = itemRepository.AsQueryable()
                     .Where(r => r.ProductID == productID && r.IsActive == true)
                     .OrderBy(r => r.MRP)
                     .Skip(pageNumber * numberOfItems)
                     .Take(numberOfItems)
                     .ToList();
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean in the question but for starters doing an order by descending then an order by renders the first one redundant. Did you mean to do a OrderByDescending().ThenBy()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LastID` will not help you with paging if you are sorting by a different field (MRP). Also, as indicated in the comments above, the first ordering is effectively ignored by adding the second.

You could consider tracking the page number that is requested and use the Skip() extension.

```
// input parameter 'page'
var itemList = itemRepository.AsQueryable()
    .Where(r => r.ProductID == productID && r.IsActive == true)       
    .OrderBy(r => r.MRP)
    .Skip( (page-1)*numberOfItems )
    .Take(numberOfItems)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: What should be that page variable?

Comment: Your previous code used LastId to support paging. Now you just need the client to send you the page number they want to view. So `page` is a page number parameter coming from the client, just like `lastId` used to be

Comment: Sorry I forgot to update, , I got it, and guess what skip works great , I will update the answer. Thanks.